# Service class to read data from yml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**I have following code:**

```
application.yml
security:
  section1:
    key1: "value1"
    key2: "value2"
  section2:
    key1: "value1"
    key2: "value2"
```

```
//Main class
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Service class**

```
@Service
public class DemoService {

    private Map<String,Section1Properties>projects=new HashMap<String,Section1Properties>();
    @Autowired
    public DemoService(SecurityProperties security) {
        this.projects=security.myConfig1();
        projects.get("section1").getKey1();
        projects.get("section1").getKey2();
    }

}
```

**Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security")
public class SecurityProperties implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String section1;
    private String section2;
    private Map<String,Section1Properties> sec1=new HashMap<String,Section1Properties>();
    private Map<String,Section2Properties> sec2=new HashMap<String,Section2Properties>();

    public Map<String,Section1Properties> myConfig1(){
        return sec1;
    }   
    public Map<String,Section2Properties> myConfig2(){
        return sec2;
    }
    public String getSection1() {
        return section1;
    }

    public void setSection1(String section1) {
        this.section1 = section1;
    }

    public String getSection2() {
        return section2;
    }

    public void setSection2(String section2) {
        this.section2 = section2;
    }

    public static class Section1Properties{
    private String key1;
     private String key2;
    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }
    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }
    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }
    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
}

    public static class Section2Properties{
        private String key1;
         private String key2;
        public String getKey1() {
            return key1;
        }
        public void setKey1(String key1) {
            this.key1 = key1;
        }
        public String getKey2() {
            return key2;
        }
        public void setKey2(String key2) {
            this.key2 = key2;
        }
    }
}
```

when I am running this code I am getting **error** like below.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demoService' defined in file [C:\Users\ABC\eclipse-workspace\demo\target\classes\com\demo\DemoService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.demo.DemoService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:314) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:295) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at com.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.demo.DemoService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       ... 19 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.demo.DemoService.(DemoService.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>       ... 21 common frames omitted

Comment: I don't get how you designed your SecurityProperties class. Why does it have maps? Why does it have properties section1 and section2 as STrings. It should have two properties section1 and section2, both of type SectionProperties. And SectionProperties should have two String properties named key1 and key2. And you would thus get the properties using security.getSection1().getKey1() and security.getSection1().getKey2().

Comment: @ JB Nizet,I want to store section1 data in sec1 map and section2 data in sec2 map.so that i can display like key value pairs as same as shown in application.yml file somewhere or can carry whereever i want.I u have any way to do that then please describe here.

Comment: Well, you can just display the properties by calling the getters. Or, if you really want a Map, then create a toMap() method and return a Map. But the properties should be easy to use and validate in the code.

Comment: @ JB Nizet ,can u write code for toMap() method according to above code.

Comment: `Map<String, SectionProperties> map = new HashMap<>(); map.put("section1", section1); map.put("section2", section2);`